# Android-Server SMS Verification code

Tags: java, android, sms

I have an android app and I want to allow a user to login using a verification code. I want to send the verification code in an SMS to the user's phone. What is the best solution to verify if the verification code matchs on the server side?

Is the  creation of  new table that contains verification codes a good idea?

Comment: You need to create a verify api call on server side. The verify codes are stored in a temp table with a phone number. User need to verify the code on your server is safe and secure. Its fine then server will send a respose like {result:success/failure}.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple ways to implement user verification on Android:

1. Some apps build it themselves with SMS / Voice APIs
2. Others use a verification specific API

With SMS / Voice APIs

- You'll need to generate a code (huge security threat)
- Send it via the channel you use primarily
- Set some kind of time delay job (queue,worker, whatever)
- Send a fallback message should you get no response
  from the user

**Nexmo’s Verify API**

Instead of paying different fees for each country, Nexmo allows you to go globally with a simple API call for a flat fee of 10 cents per verification, NOT per attempt (unsuccessful attempts will not be charged towards your account)

Verification code should arrive to your phone as an SMS. If you wait a while, you'll also get a phone call, and the code will be read to you. The timing and channels used depends on the type of number, the country, and the carrier.

You can also use Verify's Android SDK, which enables you to build Verify into your Android app by simplifying this integration. After importing this library into your app, you will only need the user's phone number, while the SDK will take care of the remaining steps required to verify your users.

Take a look at Nexmo's Verify Android SDK [here](https://github.com/Nexmo/verify-android-sdk)

Full disclosure, I work at Nexmo.